# How to control number of records in Kinesis Client library

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl, amazon-kinesis-kpl

I am trying to control number of records fetched in processRecords method of KCL, here is my KCL configuration

```
new KinesisClientLibConfiguration(
        config.getApplicationName(), config.getStreamName(), awsCredentialsProvider, workerId)
        .withInitialPositionInStream(InitialPositionInStream.LATEST)
        .withRegionName(config.getRegion())
        .withMaxRecords(config.getMaxRecords())
```

My config.getMaxRecords() is set to 500 but i am still getting ~1000-1500 records in processRecords method, i want strict upper limit as 500 since my downstream process can not handle more than that.

Comment: What I see here looks right - I hate to ask, but are you sure the config value is actually 500, and that this is the config being used? It wouldn't be the first time questions like this came from typos

Comment: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/issues/285

Comment: I have the same issue with KCL 1.9.1, I set max records as 300-500, but still getting around 1000 during the peak time.